# Scopes granted in user access token not showing up in debug mode

Tags: facebook, token, whatsapp

While debugging the fb user access tokens created for whatsapp messaging the scopes granted do not show up.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot of the debug screen with the scopes not showing up]